# "File is locked, but no other information is available" when trying to read from (NFS) folder with SAS on linux?

Tags: sas

Trying to open a `.sas` file *from a read-only NFS mount* on CentOS7 via SAS (v9.4 TS Level 1M5) with the Program Editor and getting the error

> ERROR: File is locked, but no other information is available. File=/path/to/sas/file.sas System Error Code = 37.
>
> ERROR: File is in use, /path/to/sas/file.sas

Am not sure what could be causing this. Not sure what processes could be accessing the file aside from the process I am opening the file with and have *no problems with accessing the NFS share and opening the file with other applications* on the server (eg. Pluma text editor).

Running `lslock` on the server, none of these `.sas` files show up.

If relevant, the `/etc/exports` config for the NFS mount on the exporting server I'm trying to access from the client looks like...

```sh
...
/path/to/nfs/share    myclientserver(ro,root_squash,sync) someotherserver(...) ...
...
```

Anyone with more experience have any ideas what could be going on here? Any other debugging info that should be added to this question?

Answer (score 0):

we had a similar problem but not on CENTOS. The unmount and mount fixed this problem. Have you tried?